# React Native Siri Dictation cut short by rerenders - Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native prodject.

I have an input that I use in several places in the app. I can type in it no problem, but I use siri dictation fromt the ios keyboard, the words are cut short by a rerender.

A similar questions has been asked before,
[React native dictation cuts words abruptly on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242059/react-native-dictation-cuts-words-abruptly-on-ios)
but the only answer was for class components. Is  there a way to fix this with functional components?

I tried throwing a useMemo() around the textChangeHandler, and that does allow siri to work, by blocking all state updates. But this is no good because then I have no data.

Here is my component:

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import mergeRefs from 'react-merge-refs';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const INPUT_CHANGE = 'INPUT_CHANGE';
const INPUT_BLUR = 'INPUT_BLUR';

const formatDate = date => {
  const options = {
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    year: '2-digit',
  };
  const formattedDate = new Date(date);
  const _formattedDate = formattedDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
  return _formattedDate;
};

const inputReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INPUT_CHANGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        value: action.value,
        isValid: action.isValid,
      };
    case INPUT_BLUR:
      return {
        ...state,
        touched: true,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [inputState, dispatch] = useReducer(inputReducer, {
    value: props.initialValue ? props.initialValue : '',
    isValid: props.initiallyValid ? props.initiallyValid : true,
    touched: props.initialValue ? true : false,
  });

  const { onInputChange, id } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    onInputChange(id, inputState.value, inputState.isValid);
  }, [inputState, onInputChange, id]);

  const textChangeHandler = text => {
    const emailRegex =
      /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    let isValid = true;
    if (props.required && text.trim().length === 0) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (props.email && !emailRegex.test(text.toLowerCase())) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (props.min != null && +text < props.min) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (props.max != null && +text > props.max) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (props.minLength != null && text.length < props.minLength) {
      isValid = false;
    }

    dispatch({ type: INPUT_CHANGE, value: text, isValid: isValid });
  };

  const lostFocusHandler = () => {
    dispatch({ type: INPUT_BLUR });
  };

  const inputRef = useRef();
  const getFormValue = () => {
    const inputValue = props.initialValue
      ? props.initialValue
      : inputState.value;
    if (props.date) {
      return formatDate(inputValue).toString();
    }
    return inputValue;
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ ...props.style, ...styles.container }}>
      <TextInput
        ref={mergeRefs([inputRef, ref])}
        {...props}
        value={getFormValue()}
        onChangeText={textChangeHandler}
        onBlur={lostFocusHandler}
      />

      {!inputState.isValid && inputState.touched && (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => inputRef.current.focus()}>
          <View style={{ ...props.style, ...styles.errorContainer }}>
            <Text
              testID="Auth.errorMessage"
              style={{ color: props.errorTextColor, ...styles.errorText }}
            >
              {props.errorText}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    </View>
  );
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1 },
  errorContainer: {
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
  errorText: {
    fontSize: 13,
  },
});

Input.displayName = 'Input'; //This is here only to make esLint happy

Input.propTypes = {
  date: PropTypes.bool,
  onInputChange: PropTypes.func,
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  initialValue: PropTypes.any,
  initiallyValid: PropTypes.bool,
  required: PropTypes.bool,
  email: PropTypes.bool,
  min: PropTypes.number,
  max: PropTypes.number,
  minLength: PropTypes.number,
  style: PropTypes.object,
  errorText: PropTypes.string,
  errorTextColor: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I forgot to answer this before I figured out a solution. It's a bit hacky, but I just wrapped the contents of getFormValue in a 5ms timeout, and that was enough to keep it from bugging out.

```
  const getFormValue = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const inputValue = props.initialValue
        ? props.initialValue
        : inputState.value;
      if (props.date) {
        return formatDate(inputValue).toString();
      }
      return inputValue;
    }, 5);
  };
```